# Code works fine from test case but not when called via HTTP

Tags: java, arrays, elasticsearch-5

I have some code that is working fine when called from a test case, but when I call it via HTTP (using a get request) I get a strange error:

```
ArrayStoreException occured : org.apache.http.impl.cookie.RFC2965VersionAttributeHandler
```

Does anyone have any ideas about what's causing this?

The offending code (with logging removed) looks like this:

```
public static void deleteIndex(String companyKey, String regionKey) throws IOException {
    RestClient client = Elasticsearch.getClient();
    HttpEntity query = createQueryForDelete(companyKey, regionKey);
    Response response = client.performRequest(
        "POST", "/products/_delete_by_query", new HashMap<String, String>(), query);
}
```

With the offending line being:

```
        Response response = client.performRequest(
        "POST", "/products/_delete_by_query", new HashMap<String, String>(), query);
```

I have built a test case that calls the controller explicitly, and that works fine too. So I don't think it's related to the code, but something to do with the way HTTP works. But since the functional code is all in a model rather than in the controller I can't imagine what the difference is.

The controller just looks like this:

```
public static void deleteIndex(String companyKey, String regionKey) throws IOException {
    ElasticIndex.deleteIndex(companyKey,regionKey);
}
```

And `ElasticIndex.deleteIndex` is the method initially defined above.

Any clues about how the `ArrayStoreException` might be caused, will be much appreciated.

The full stacktrace is:

> Execution exception (In /app/models/ElasticSearch/ElasticIndex.java
>   around line 98) ArrayStoreException occured :
>   org.apache.http.impl.cookie.RFC2965VersionAttributeHandler
>
> play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException:
>   org.apache.http.impl.cookie.RFC2965VersionAttributeHandler    at
>   play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:231)     at
>   Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ArrayStoreException:
>   org.apache.http.impl.cookie.RFC2965VersionAttributeHandler    at
>   org.apache.http.impl.cookie.DefaultCookieSpecProvider.create(DefaultCookieSpecProvider.java:92)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies.process(RequestAddCookies.java:152)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.protocol.ImmutableHttpProcessor.process(ImmutableHttpProcessor.java:133)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.MainClientExec.prepareRequest(MainClientExec.java:520)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.MainClientExec.prepare(MainClientExec.java:146)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.start(DefaultClientExchangeHandlerImpl.java:124)
>     at
>   org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.InternalHttpAsyncClient.execute(InternalHttpAsyncClient.java:141)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequestAsync(RestClient.java:343)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequestAsync(RestClient.java:325)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:218)
>     at
>   org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient.performRequest(RestClient.java:191)
>     at
>   models.ElasticSearch.ElasticIndex.deleteIndex(ElasticIndex.java:98)
>     at
>   models.ElasticSearch.ElasticIndex.deleteIndex(ElasticIndex.java:78)
>     at controllers.Application.deleteIndex(Application.java:304)    at
>   play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:544)
>     at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:494)    at
>   play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:489)
>     at
>   play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:458)
>     at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:162)    ... 1 more

Comment: When asking about an exception, always post the complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @JBNizet

Comment: In the end this was related to the Apache HttpCore .jar being a slightly older one. I updated that to 4.4.6 from 4.4.5 and it worked. But I never got to the root of the issue.